# Referencing Bash jobs in other jobs

Tags: bash, shell, jobs, job-control

I want to reference a background Bash job in another background Bash job.  Is that possible?

For example, say I start a background job:

```
$ long_running_process &
[1] 12345
```

Now I want something to happen when that job finishes, so I can use `wait`:

```
$ wait %1 && thing_to_happen_after_long_running_process_finishes
```

However, that will block, and I want my terminal back to do other stuff, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> does nothing.

Attempting to start this in the background in the first place instead fails:

```
$ { wait %1 && thing_to_happen_after_long_running_process_finishes; } &
[2] 12346
-bash: line 3: wait: %1: no such job
$ jobs
[1]-  Running     long_running_process &
[2]+  Exit 127    { wait %1 && thing_to_happen_after_long_running process_finishes; }
```

Is there some way to reference one job using `wait` in another background job?

I see this behaviour using GNU Bash 4.1.2(1)-release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shell can only `wait` on its own children. Since backgrounding a job creates a new shell, a `wait` in that shell can only wait on its own children, not the children of its parent (i.e., the shell from which the background-wait forked). For what you want, you need to plan ahead:

```
long_running_process && thing_to_happen_after &
```

---

There is one alternative:

```
long_running_process &
LRP_PID=$!

{ while kill -0 $LRP_PID 2> /dev/null; do sleep 1; done; thing_to_happen_after; } &
```

This would set up a loop that tries to ping your background process once a second. When the process is complete, the `kill` will fail, and move on to the post-process program. It carries the *slight* risk that your process would exit and another process would be given the same process ID between checks, in which case the `kill` would become confused and think your process was still running, when in fact it is the new one. But it's very slight risk, and actually it might be OK if `thing_to_happen_after` is delayed a little longer until there is no process with ID `$LRP_PID`.

Comment: Thought that might be the case. Damn.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
  x2=$(long_running_process && thing_to_happen_after_long_running_process_finishes ) &
```